# What is the plural form of DVD?

Tags: plural-forms, acronyms

> I own lots of DVD's.

> I own lots of DVDs

> I own lots of DVD.

How can I properly indicate the plural for acronyms in English?

Comment: Probably means ***own***

Comment: I own lots of DVDs.

Comment: From ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym

Comment: As long as you don't use periods between the letters, you do **not** use an apostrophe.

Comment: You only need an apostrophe if you want to indicate possession. Or if you want to pluralize something like the name of a letter: *It's spelled with two l's.* As far as I know, you still just add an s to initialisms that are written with periods: There is only one U.K. and there could never be two U.K.s.

Answer (score 9):

This issue has been addressed several times on ELU, including [*Plurals of acronyms, letters, numbers — use an apostrophe or not?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/)
, and [*What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym)

The bottom line is it's largely a matter of stylistic preference whether to include an apostrophe or not in OP's exact context. To some extent, the *average* preference varies over time, and currently *most* style guides advise against it except where comprehension would be seriously compromised by its absence. Thus...

> - *I own lots of **DVDs*** (generally preferred, even with the uncapitalised form ***dvds***)
> - *I know lots of **bi's*** (= ***bisexuals***, usually apostrophized purely for comprehension)
> - *Mind your **p's** and **q's*** (almost always [apostrophized today](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mind-your-ps-and-qs.html) for legibility)

---

OP's third alternative *(I own lots of **DVD**)* would *never* be acceptable, because ***dvd*** (whether capitalized or not) isn't a "mass noun". This is a matter of "real" (spoken) language, whereas the apostrophe is just a matter of orthography (a written form attempting to *represent* speech).

Answer (score 5):

*I own lots of DVDs.*

*DVD* is an initialism, not an acronym. See [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/initialisms-american).

Comment: Good use of reference.

Answer (score 2):

### How to properly indicate the plural regarding acronyms in English?

It's simple. Think about the full form and you'll have a clue!

We call Managing Director *MD* in short, don't we?

Now think of a sentence.

> There are five Managing Directors

***Do you see an apostrophe 's?*** ~ No, you don't. That's it...write it the same way with acronym

> There are five Managing Directors 
>  
>   There are five   M-----------D--------s (no apostrophe) = MDs

Now think of another example:

> I'm talking about the Managing Directors' cars (say, there are 5 managing directors) 
>   I'm talking about the M-----------D--------s' cars (with apostrophe) = MDs' cars

Now for a singular use:

> I'm talking about the Managing Director's cars (say, there is only 1 managing director) 
>   I'm talking about the M-----------D--------'s cars (with apostrophe) = MD's car

Hope this helps.